# Где брать знания?

Tags: python, sql, linux, django

я студент вуза, со специальностью, никак не связанной с программированием.
Я изучил основы питона, сейчас сижу на алгоритмах и структурах данных, параллельно изучая язык запросов sql.
Дальше изучу linux и фрейм django. Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что совершенно не понимаю, как многие вещи связаны,не хватает каких-то основ. Изучаю в основном по курсам со stepik. По этой не хватает теории, поэтому буду очень рад, если порекомендуете какие-то книги с пояснениями. Прошу, кто уже состоялся и работает в этой сфере - дайте минимальный набор книг и ваши рекомендации.

Заранее благодарю, надеюсь отыщу тут ответ.

Comment: Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow! Этот вопрос не сюда.  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Ни одна теория вас не научит, как связывать несвязанное и впихивать не впихуемое, пока не попадете на работу с проектом, в которм это все придется реализовать, связать, впихнуть и так, что бы работало. Попробуйте создать проект с базой данных и вэб мордой для многопользовательского использования, допустим, туду лист